# Is there any other way to create combo box using c# (rather than SelectionChangedEventHandler)

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, combobox, silverlight-5.0

I am working in c# and using silverlight5. I have undergone a problem that i have to create combo box using just c# (not xaml) because i doing it dynamically.

I have used  `SelectionChangedEventHandler` to do so but i wanna replace it using some other way but don't know which way ?

currently i have this working code:

```
 ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
 if (param.Type == "ComboBox") // I am reading xml if there is ComboBox in its node then i create combo box using c# and this "param" is an object
 {

     TextBlock txtblk2 = new TextBlock(); //This textBlock is to print the selected value from Combo Box

     cb.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(comboBox1_SelectionChanged);
     cb.SelectedIndex = cb.Items.Count - 1;
     txtblk2.Text = cb.SelectedValue.ToString() + " millions";

 }
 void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
 {
     MessageBox.Show("comboBox1_SelectionChanged1");
     txtblk2.Text = cb.SelectedValue.ToString() + " millions";
     txtblk2.FontSize = 14;
 }
```

**Could some one please write me any equivalent way to achieve the same using c# only (Not Xaml) which must support silverlight5 ?**
Would be a big help. Thanks.

**Why c# only ?**

Actually i will have xml dynamically whose structure i don't know and i will deserialize it  and i will use it's object obtained to access the xml node values if i come across any node  having `<Type>ComboBox<Type>` then i will create the combo box as i have created above (using selection changed event) the same i have to achieve but without using xaml and selction changed event.

Comment: "i have to [...] using just c# (not xaml) because i doing it dynamically" that's not really a valid reason, you can declare xaml to deal with dynamic content. Define a `DataTemplate` that is used whenever your data (parsed xml) contains a _combo_-Node.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use XAML? You can bind ListBox with items bound to collection of objects with DataTemplate set to for example:

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding DynamicItems}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And in code behind:

```
     if (param.Type == "ComboBox")
     {
          DynamicItem item = new DynamicItem(){Name="param.Name"};
          DynamicItems.Add(item);
     }
```

Then ComboBox will be created automatically. I prefer this way because creating UI elements in code behind is something that looks awful.

I know it is not solution for your problem, you have to just adjust it to your problem.

Comment: Thanks but i know to do this way. even i know to do using selectionevent changed. But i dont want to do using this way. Do you know any other way using c# only?

Comment: Why do you want to do this with c# only? What's wrong with your code then? What do you mean by equivalent? Say more precisely what do you mean. Maybe try to use Binding.SetBinding to make that bindings working from c# only

Comment: Could you please let me know if you understood what i am trying to do ?

Comment: I don't know if your code is ok. You create combobox and this combobox has no items. And you set its selected index. Have you forgotten to add items? If yes, then what is the structure of the object param? You know it or not? As you wrote, you don't know the structure of entire xml, not single param right?

Comment: Yes my code is OK. I have already added the items in combo box but i wanted to give just the useful code.Martin's solution is very close to what i wanna achieve but there is an exception that:Catastrophic failure (Exception de HRESULT : 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) on line "new Binding("SelectedValue") { Source = cb, StringFormat = "{0} millions" }); "

Comment: sllauncher.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.30214.0\fr\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll' A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Windows.dll on output window of VStudio

Answer (score 1):

You can set bindings programmatically...
...but again, I strongly recommend you read about `DataTemplates`, you won't get happy with your "c#-code-only" approach.

```
if (param.Type == "ComboBox")
{
    ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock(){FontSize = 14};
    tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty,
      new Binding("SelectedValue")
      {
         Source = cb, StringFormat = "{0} millions"
      });
}
```

Comment: Catastrophic failure (Exception de HRESULT : 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) on line "new Binding("SelectedValue")
      {
         Source = cb, StringFormat = "{0} millions"
      });
"

Comment: sllauncher.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.30214.0\fr\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Windows.dll on output window of VStudio